# Why not define primitive roots of unity for a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Given positive integer $n$, an element $\alpha$ of a field is an ***n*th root of unity** if $\alpha^n=1$.
It is a **primitive *n*th root of unity** if $\alpha^n=1$ and $\alpha^m\neq1$ for $0<m<n$.

I've seen this definition of primitive roots of unity for fields, and even for rings with unity, but not for groups. Would the definition make sense, and if not, why not?

**Remark** I suppose if this definition makes sense, the torsion subgroup would precisely contain the ***n*th roots of unity** for each $n$?

Comment: For groups, aren't these just the elements of order $n$?

Comment: Yes, if primitive.
If not, I imagine we could just characterize elements which are $n$th root of unity as those "elements whose order divides n"? Which seems a bit of a mouthful.

Does anybody know any texts which use the phrase "roots of unity" (or another term) in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a group, we already have a name for this: we call it an **element of order $n$**.  In a ring, it's helpful to be more specific -- saying "$x$ has order $n$'' might mean that $n\cdot x=0$ or that $x^n=1$.

Comment: @Misha: you beat me to it -- but I had to answer, because I don't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: Yes, thanks.
I should have just asked about "roots of unity" and omitted "primitive". Then there might be reason to use the term "$n$th roots of unity" for those elements whose order divides n.

Comment: @swensonj: it is good to have the answers as _answers_ rather than hidden away in comments anyway. Welcome to MSE!